# if, elif not working as expected

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I do not know why but the `if`, `elif` in the following code is not working as I expect it to. However,

- It works perfectly when I type 1 to 7
- it works perfectly when I type 0 8 or 9 (it says "Try again")
- It does not work if I type 10 to 69, 100 to any number

When I say it does not work I mean it prints

```
my_shape_num = h_m.how_many()
```

**But I do not know why. It has to stop if choice is not between 1  and 7**

```
def main(): # Display the main menu
    while True:
        print
        print "  Draw a Shape"
        print "  ============"
        print
        print "  1 - Draw a triangle"
        print "  2 - Draw a square"
        print "  3 - Draw a rectangle"
        print "  4 - Draw a pentagon"
        print "  5 - Draw a hexagon"
        print "  6 - Draw an octagon"
        print "  7 - Draw a circle"
        print
        print "  X - Exit"
        print

        choice = raw_input('  Enter your choice: ')

        if (choice == 'x') or (choice == 'X'):
            break

        elif (choice >= '1' and choice <= '7'):
            my_shape_num = h_m.how_many()
            if ( my_shape_num is None): 
                continue

            d_s.start_point() # start point on screen

            if choice == '1': 
                d_s.draw_triangle(my_shape_num) 
            elif choice == '2': 
                d_s.draw_square(my_shape_num) 
            elif choice == '3':             
                d_s.draw_rectangle(my_shape_num) 
            elif choice == '4':             
                d_s.draw_pentagon(my_shape_num) 
            elif choice == '5':             
                d_s.draw_hexagon(my_shape_num) 
            elif choice == '6':             
                d_s.draw_octagon(my_shape_num) 
            elif choice == '7': 
                d_s.draw_circle(my_shape_num)

        else:
            print
            print '  Try again'
            print
```

---

Edit: Ok, sorted:

```
choice = raw_input('  Enter your choice: ')

if (choice == 'x') or (choice == 'X'):
    break


try:
    choice = int(choice)
    if (1 <= choice <= 7):

        my_shape_num = h_m.how_many()
        if ( my_shape_num is None): 
            continue

        d_s.start_point() # start point on screen

        if choice == 1: 
            d_s.draw_triangle(my_shape_num) 
        elif choice == 2: 
            d_s.draw_square(my_shape_num) 
        elif choice == 3:             
            d_s.draw_rectangle(my_shape_num) 
        elif choice == 4:             
            d_s.draw_pentagon(my_shape_num) 
        elif choice == 5:             
            d_s.draw_hexagon(my_shape_num) 
        elif choice == 6:             
            d_s.draw_octagon(my_shape_num) 
        elif choice == 7: 
            d_s.draw_circle(my_shape_num)

    else:
        print
        print '  Number must be from 1 to 7!'
        print

except ValueError:
    print
    print '  Try again'
    print
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strings are compared [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order): `'10'` is greater than `'1'` but less than `'7'`. Now consider this code:

```
elif (choice >= '1' and choice <= '7'):
```

In addition to accepting `'7'`, this will accept any string beginning with `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` or `6`.

To fix, convert `choice` to integer as soon as you've tested for `'x'`, and use integer comparisons thereafter.

Comment: thanks. I could not figure it out how to deal with other inputs which is not number.

Comment: i have done this: `choice = raw_input('  Enter your choice: ')

        if (choice == 'x') or (choice == 'X'):
            break

        
        try:
            choice = int(choice)
            if (1 <= choice <= 7):
                
                if choice == 1: 
                    d_s.draw_triangle(my_shape_num)
            
            else:
                print
                print '  Number must be from 1 to 7!'
                print
                
        except ValueError:
            print
            print '  Try again'
            print`

Comment: @baris22: It's hard to read the code pasted into the comment, but you're on the right track: I think trying `int(choice)` and catching `ValueError` is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

```
'43' < '7'           # True
43 < 7               # False
int('43') < int('7') # False
```

You're comparing strings (text), so the order is like a dictionary. You need to convert them into integers (numbers), so that comparisons put them in counting order.

Then, course, you also need to be prepared for people typing things that aren't numbers:

```
int('hi')       # ValueError
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you are using string for comparing... try

```
choice = int(choice)
```

before if, elif block and change their comparisons to

```
if choice == 1:
```

(without quotes)